# Stop two polygons from overlapping by removing equal area from both

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, shapely

I need to create a hitbox for two lines, the lines never cross. To do so, I use shapely buffer, which gives me polygon around the line that serves as a hitbox (shown on image below).

The problem is when two lines are close together - hitboxes overlap. Because of this, click (shown as red dot) on the black line could be registered as a click on the blue line because the hitbox overlaps the black line.

[image]

To fix this I need to shrink both polygons in the area of intersection like this:
[image]

Is it possible to do this in python with shapely or some other library? If not, what are some algorithms that solve this?

Comment: Have you searched for it? What did you get?